# wordpress and javascript plugin compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I program a plugin where I use javascript, for example this line :

```
$( "input:radio[name=base]:checked" ).val();
```

When I put the shortcode on page and click the button to display an alert with the value obtained is not working but if I add the javascript script (cdn) if it works but the menu page generated Worpress stops working, I supposed that my plugin work with javascript that comes in the template. What is the problem?

Comment: Without seeing more code, that is impossible to tell, you might want to update your question.

Comment: It's possible your scripts could be conflicting, have you tried changing the order in which you render them to the page?  Also are you loading your scripts synchronously or asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finely use this:

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {

/*------------------------------------------------*/    
/* code here */
/*------------------------------------------------*/    

  });
})(jQuery);
```

now work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about jQuery, not pure JavaScript.

Check to see if `jQuery( "input:radio[name=base]:checked" ).val();` works, replace all of the `$` symbols with `jQuery` to debug.

WordPress has a [no-conflict mode enabled by default](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers). You can wrap your jQuery in the following to use the `$` shorthand:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
  // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

It sounds like you should brush up on [JavaScript basics](http://thinkcodenyc.com/meteor-js-tutorials/javascript-basics-meteor/) while you're at it.